# How to cite an entire section I rephrased from a book using APA style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Let us say that I'm summarizing a chapter from a book.

I'm rephrasing an entire section, let us say that the section is about scheduling algorithms which are taken from operating systems concepts book.
Let us say that this section has many subsections, and there are paragraphs under each subsection.

Shall I add a citation to every paragraph (same citation) or shall I add the citation at the beginning of the section or beside the title? Or at the end of the section?

Comment: I'd cite the source just once but make sure it's completely clear how much of the summary is just paraphrasing the source.